# How can I set my Mac Mini to output 16x10 resolution over a VGA cable?

Tags: mac, display, vga, mac-mini

I have a 16x10 monitor that I use for my other computers (native resolution 1920x1200), and I want to use it for my old Mac Mini too. I have it connected via a VGA cable to the DVI-to-VGA adapter that came with the Mac Mini, but the only resolutions that come up in my "Displays" dialog aren't good native resolutions.

Here's a sampling of some of the ones I can choose:

```
1024 x 768, 60 Hz
1280 x 768, 60 Hz
1400 x 1050, 60 Hz
1600 x 1200, 60 Hz
1920 x 1440, 60 Hz
2048 x 1536, 60 Hz
```

And there are some higher framerate versions of most of those.

Is there a way to get my Mac Mini to put out 1920 x 1200? Or even just 1440 x 900?

Thanks.